# How to post to a web service that has implemented Single Sign On?

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2008, single-sign-on

(sorry in advance this got a bit long)

The web service in question is running on IIS that has enabled Windows Integrated Authentication.

The development environment is C#, Visual Studio 2008. I can use 2010 if I need to. My old projects are still in 2008.

The two applications I have are my 'fiddling around apps'.

One uses the standard methodology of calling a web service (i.e. adding the web reference, built the proxy classes, etc).

The other basically takes an external XML file and does an HTTP post to the URL (I built it before I knew of the existence of SOAPUI).

So now the web service is going to be behind SSO and I'm trying to figure out how to call the web service with these two different applications.

I assume there is two different ways to do it. The standard way is just to add the line

```
     myproxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

This works great in my standard application.

How would I go about doing this manually in the HTTP post application?

I assume the same line of code would work on the HttpWebRequest object, but I would like to give it a shot manually.

thanks and again sorry for the length.

lee

Comment: Edited to make the question more obvious.